# Why should I use cobbler over normal PXEBOOT server?

Tags: redhat, cobbler, pxe-boot

Maybe it's me but I find it easier to manage my simple pxeboot server just by editing the default file under `/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg`. I have my kickstart file available over NFS along with the DVD extracted to a centralize mount point. Other than PXEBOOT, what benefit would I get from running cobbler? It was confusing at first but I finally got the hang off it. The only benefit I see is being able to force a server to install an OS on demand. Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cobbler system is designed to manage the inventory and operating systems of many machines over time. While its feasible for you to manage your 1 pxelinux.cfg, think of a service provider environment where we frequently have to install different operating systems for customers. It can really improve the quality of life for the ops people who would normally be either installing via CD/Flash or setting up a pxeboot in the method you described.

Cobbler is really a centralized system to manage the installations of many systems.